# converting two digit integer into single digit inside a python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
list1 = [6,10,4,8,2,12,10]
```

I want to convert all the integers in `list1` which are  greater than or equal to 10 into a single integer. For example, `10: 1+0=1` , `12: 1+2=3`. The output list should be:

```
list1 = [6,1,4,8,2,3,1]
```

Can anyone please help me with the logic? The logic I tried so far which is not working:

```
for itr in list1:
    if ( itr >= 10):
        itr1 = str(itr)
        itr2 = eval(itr[0]+itr[1])
```

Comment: How about `99`? Should it be `9 + 9 => 1 + 8 = 9`?

Comment: Well try `print(itr[0]+itr[1])` and see what you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For small numbers you can `sum` up the individual digits by iterating over the `str(num)`

```
[sum(int(c) for c in str(num)) for num in list1]
```

For larger numbers where the sum of the digits can be `>9`, you can use `divmod` to avoid converting to `str`:

```
def reduce_num(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(divmod(n, 10))
    return n

[reduce_num(num) for num in list1]
```

Or none iteratively (slight fix to @suspicious_dog):

```
[n-9*int((n-1)/9) for n in list1]    # change to /9.0 for Py2
```

Comment: Although the OP is not explicit, this will give >1 digits for cases like `28` -> `10`

Comment: Good point. Added an alternative approach to reducing the number.

Answer (score 8):

None of these examples will work if the sum of the first iteration is greater than 10, e.g. `999 -> 27`. Interpreting this scenario as `999 -> 27 -> 9`, you can use the following function:

```
>>> def digit_sum(n):
...     while n > 9:
...         n = sum(int(d) for d in str(n))
...     return n
...
>>> [digit_sum(n) for n in [1, 3, 999, 10, 234, 1234132341]]
[1, 3, 9, 1, 9, 6]
```

This also assumes that all integers are positive.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised nobody has yet to mention that this is the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) operation. We can use the formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula) (Thanks, Wikipedia!) to calculate the root without explicit loops or recursion:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return 1 + (n - 1) % 9 if n else 0

nums = [6,10,4,8,2,12,10]
roots = [digital_root(num) for num in nums]
print(roots)
```

Comment: Doesn't handle `0`s correctly but relatively easy to fix `1 + (n - 1) % 9 if n else 0`. Or: `n-9*int((n-1)/9.0)`

Comment: @AChampion Thanks! You're right. It seems like the given formula assumes [truncating division/modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)  (like in Java), whereas Python uses floor division/modulo. I've applied your fix.

Answer (score 2):

`repr` the int, map back to `int`s, and `sum`?

```
>>> list1=[6,10,4,8,2,12,10]
[6, 10, 4, 8, 2, 12, 10]
>>> list2=list(map(lambda n: sum(map(int,repr(n))),list1))
[6, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 1]
```

Edit: according to [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), the listcomp method is faster for shorter lists, but if you have a few hundred or more items, mapping is faster.

Additionally, if you're iterating over the list later, you can keep it as a `map` object and avoid the extra time for casting back to a `list`:

```
>>> list2=map(lambda n: sum(map(int,repr(n))),list1)
<map object at 0x0000021AC74C3D30>
>>> for i in list2: print(i)
6
1
4
8
2
3
1
```